# Retrieve Data from Isilon Server

Tags: powershell, isilon

I would like to retrieve folder info from Isilon server which is installed in my Local VM.

Below are the FolderInfo that i required to collect: CreateDate, AccessDate, ModifyDate, DirName,FileCount,Count,Size, FullAccessPath

using the link http://doc.isilon.com/onefs/7.0.2/help/en-us/

I see that i can get these information (CreateDate, AccessDate, ModifyDate, DirName,FileCount,Count,Size) from Extended property of the powershell. Can any one help me on retrieving the fullaccesspath of the folder or file.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: For Retriving the Full path of the directory i didn't find any way.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please upgrade OneFS away from 7.0.2
   You are programming against a very old (and obsolete) version.
2. I could not find information on "FullAccessPath" in MS docs ... can you provide example code with output pulling "FullAccessPath" from a local file/folder ?
3. If this "FullAccessPath" is dealing with ACLs ( like setfacl ) then you must connect to SMB share from Isilon which sets your account with "run as root" flag.